# how to see the git commands executed by Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In **Eclipse** when you interact with a **Subversion** server, there is an **SVN** console which displays all the svn commands that the ide performs against the subversion server.

- Was there an equivalent for **Intellij** and **Git**?

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the actual git commands with timestamps in the "Version Control" view.

You can enable that in View -> Tool Windows -> Version Control

*Update for more recent versions:*

The tool window is now named according to your VCS e.g. Git, Mercurial. To see the commands, you need to switch to the `Console` tab.

Comment: In recent versions the `Version Control` is renamed based on the tool you use. E.g. for `Git` it is `View -> Tool Windows -> Git`. (And open `Console` tab.)

Comment: @exmaxx thanks for *And open Console tab* hint. stelmod I think it would be helpful for future readers if you can add it to the answer itself.

Comment: Is there a way to open `Console` tab if that has been previously closed?

Comment: Just execute any Git command, like fetch (`Cmd + T`) and it will appear again.

Answer (score 5):

Intellij 2020.2 this option can be seen in the console section of git, shortcut for vcs(git here) is alt+9, see the screeen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As written in the Intellij IDEA documentation (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-console-tab.html#26ed03a2):

> The Console tab only appears when you execute version control-related commands. If you close this tab, all previous input will be lost.

So, if you close the console tab, you need to execute a git command from IDEA Git menu (like "fetch", for instance) and the console tab will reopen, automagically !